# Best way for Extracting numbers separated by spaces? in C

Tags: c, spaces

What is the best way to extract the numbers from say "55 117 28" separated by spaces in order for me to store them in variables and do arithmetic equation afterwards.
ie:

user input : 55 117 25
.
.
.

```
printf(" The Total is %.2f\n", total);  // prints 197.00

printf(" The first number * secondNumber is %.2f\n", total);  // prints 6435.00
```

EDIT: Just to make this clear also, I am not looking for the answer of my arithmetic examples, but rather a way to extract the numbers from user inputs separated by spaces, such as "55 48 862 21"  OR maybe "45 89 631 574 85 12 745 685 2541..." so on

Comment: Are you reading them as string?? Why don't you read them as numbers??

Comment: Im gonna have to store "55 117 25" as string wouldn't I? That way I could extract each numbers separated by spaces and convert them to floats right?

Comment: No, directly read as floating-point numbers, so you don't have to do the extraction part

Comment: What's the command for directly reading them to store as float. Cause I know in Java, I would have to use string tokens and do a for loop to convert the tokens..

Comment: One answer is already there. Just change `%d` to `%lf` if you want it as float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int wordCount(const char *s);//

int main(void){
    char line[4096];

    printf("user input : ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    int wc = wordCount(line);//number of elements in the space-delimited
    double nums[wc];

    int len, c = 0;
    char *s = line;
    double x, total=0.0;
    while(1==sscanf(s, "%lf%n", &x, &len)){
        total += (nums[c++] = x);
        s += len;
    }
    printf(" The Total is %.2f\n", total);
    printf(" The first number * secondNumber is %.2f\n", nums[0] * nums[1]);
    return 0;
}

int wordCount(const char *s){
    char prev = ' ';
    int wc = 0;

    while(*s){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(*s)){
            ++wc;
        }
        prev = *s++;
    }
    return wc;
}
```

Comment: How does the sscanf able to parse the string input and recognize that spaces(' ') splits the string and store the numbers to num[c]?

Comment: @xpluffy `scanf` family will skip the space character before the specified such as `%lf` (%d,%s..etc). e.g like `while(isspace(*s))++s;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696466/populating-2d-array-of-ints-from-string-in-c/25705605#25705605

Comment: +1 Very nicely done with the pre-scan and `"%n"`.  Note: `c` _may_ be less than `wc` as non-numeric text may be in `line`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x;
int sum = 0;


while ( scanf( "%d", &x ) > 0 ) sum += x;
```

If you want extract numbers from as string as for example

```
char numbers[] = "55 117 25";
```

then you can use `sscanf` ibstead of `scanf`

For example

```
while ( sscanf( numbers, "%d", &x ) > 0 ) sum += x;
```

To read a string of numbers you can use function `fgets`.

As for the format specifier for float numbers then you already specified it in your question.

Comment: Upvoted, though I think OP wants `%lf` and a `double`

Comment: @abligh I do not see where he enters doubles.

Comment: He's not providing non-integers, but if you look at the `printf` in the penultimate para of the question, he appears to be printing the total as a float (`%.2f`), implying he wants them summed in a floating point manner. Moreover he says 'numbers' rather than 'integers', and numbers include non-integers, albeit that his example does not include them. Easy enough change to your source ...

Comment: @abligh One more I do not see where he enters doubles. To output numbers he can in any format using casting.

Comment: I'm presuming he's not going to be summing integers and printing them as `double`. I think the core point is he says 'numbers', not 'integers'.

Comment: @abligh  One more it is totally unimportant what types of numbers he is going to read or write. I showed an example (approach) how the task can be done. Is it clear?

Comment: Indeed, which is why I upvoted this! I was just telling OP how to make it add `double`s instead. After all, in the comments he says "What's the command for directly reading them to store as float."